# How can I wrap a c++ library (.h & .lib files) using Python?

Tags: python, c++

I have a c++ library containing only `.h` and `.lib` files (**no** `cpp` files) for communicating with a piece of hardware and I need to use this library from Python. I don't have much experience with c/++, so it's all a little alien to me.

The `.h` files look something like this:

```
#define MSG_DLL_VERSION 10

typedef struct {
   ULONG ulDLLVersion;
   // vipmsg variables
   PMSGACCOUNTS pMsgAccounts;
   PMSGSEGMENT  pMsgSegment;
   USHORT       usMsgSegmentNum;
} MSGSTATICDATA, *PMSGSTATICDATA;

VOID msgGetDLLRedirections ( PMSGSTATICDATA *pData ); 

VOID msgSetDLLRedirections ( PMSGSTATICDATA pData );
```

Looking around, here's what I've found:

- Cython is primarily for C. It *can* do c++, but requires the `.cpp` files
- Boost.Python also requires `.cpp` files
- cffi is C only
- ctypes is C only

So, what would be the best approach?

Comment: As a rule, python does not "understand" C++, as you have found out. You will need to wrap your C++ functions with C wrappers first.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Is there an automated way to do this?

Comment: I'm not aware of any automated way of doing this. May be a better choice to try to find a C library that does the same thing (or a Python library?)

Comment: @MatsPetersson unfortunately that isn't an option; it's specific to a piece of hardware that I'm trying to communicate with.

Answer (score 1):

> Boost.Python also requires .cpp files

No it does not. You can wrap your library with Boost.Python. The way you expose C++ code using Boost.Python is to write a shared library using the various macros provided by Boost.Python.

The [documentation for Boost.Python demonstrates](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/exposing.html) wrapping this C++ type:

```
struct World
{
    void set(std::string msg) { this->msg = msg; }
    std::string greet() { return msg; }
    std::string msg;
};
```

The wrapper looks like this:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
using namespace boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
{
    class_<World>("World")
        .def("greet", &World::greet)
        .def("set", &World::set)
    ;
}
```

You can do that with your library. You do need to write the wrapper. But the fact that the class and methods being wrapped are defined in a .lib library file rather than a .cpp source file is irrelevant.

---

**Update**

Looking at the sample code from the header file this seems much more like a C style library than C++. You could certainly use Boost.Python for that. SWIG would also be an option. Or ctypes.

Comment: Thanks David, I'll take another look at the docs. I've added a little snippet from the `.h` files. They mostly look like that, not so much like your example. Is Boost.Python still the way to go?

Comment: Looks like a plain C interface to me.